# Functions which are provably total in second order peano arithmetic

Tags: logic, arithmetic, proof-theory, type-theory, lambda-calculus

Girard has a representation theorem claiming:

> The functions representable in $F$ are exactly those which are provably total in second-order peano arithmetic $PA_2$.

I believe the usual way to prove a function total in $PA_2$ is by induction. Does it matter on which ordinal we do induction on? If so, do we know anything about which classes of functions are provably total under induction for each ordinal?

Comment: Does it matter on which ordinal we do induction on? Matter for what purpose? It matters very much for which functions you can prove total: for example, induction up to $\varepsilon_0$ gets you only the functions that first-order PA proves total (a similar ordinal analysis for $PA_2$ itself is currently out of reach, though). Generally, these questions belong to the realm of reverse mathematics. Check out e.g. [Avigad's survey](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Talks/survey1.pdf), especially from page 18 onward.

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29519/what-functions-can-system-f-not-compute

Comment: https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~htowsner/prooftheory/ReverseMath.pdf